# Question about hFlush and lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, io, monads, lazy-evaluation, pointfree

I've got three definitions of the same function:

```hs
prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt = (getLine <*) . (hFlush stdout <*) . putStrLn

prompt' :: String -> IO String
prompt' str = do
    putStrLn str
    hFlush stdout
    getLine

prompt'' :: String -> IO String
prompt'' str = putStrLn str >> hFlush stdout >> getLine
```

`prompt'` and `prompt''` both flush stdout before running `getLine`, but not `prompt`. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that's not what you asked for. Since

```
prompt = (getLine <*) . (hFlush stdout <*) . putStrLn
```

we can just add an argument to see what we get:

```
prompt str = ((getLine <*) . (hFlush stdout <*) . putStrLn) str
           = getLine <* hFlush stdout <* putStrLn str
```

This asks to run the actions `getLine`, `hFlush stdout`, and `putStrLn str`, in that order. (Then the result value of that sequence of actions is whatever result value `getLine` had at the very beginning.) You want this instead:

```
prompt str = putStrLn str *> hFlush stdout *> getLine
```

or:

```
prompt = (*> getLine) . (*> hFlush stdout) . putStrLn
```

(In fact, the default buffering in most cases is line buffering or less, and you are calling `putStrLn`, not `putStr`, so *none* of these solutions actually need a call to `hFlush stdout`!)

Comment: This may be a case of confusing `(<*)` with `flip (*>)`, which I've certainly been guilty of